# Is "urban-rural gap" a proper English term for a disparity between urban and rural areas or just a word-for-word translation from Chinese?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, compound-adjectives

I came across this phrase when I was reading a research paper. Here's a quote from the abstract:

> I find that the **urban-rural gap** accounts for 40% of mean country inequality and much of its cross-country variation.

After doing some research on the internet, I've found out that "urban-rural gap" is frequently used on Chinese and Taiwanese news sites. Personally, I've never seen this wording before so I'm not sure if this is a direct translation from Chinese. Is this a proper English term for a disparity between urban and rural areas or just an artifact of a word-for-word translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=urban+rural&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Curban%20rural%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Curban%20rural%3B%2Cc0) (which searches many published books) gives some usage for the phrase "urban-rural", which peaks towards about 1990. There are no hits for "urban-rural gap".

The usage of "urban-rural" varies. You can have "urban-rural areas" or "urban-rural" interactions. These are in in British English and American English results. I think that the reason that your search is skewed towards Chinese and Taiwanese news sites is likely to do with current study on the urban-rural gap in those countries. It may be a direct translation in those instances, but it is an understandable combination of English words, and has been used in previous works, too.

Answer (score 7):

As a native speaker of UK English, former language teacher and currently a full-time translator, the phrase seems perfectly natural to me. It's just another way of describing the difference between town and country.

Comment: urban areas and rural areas. So yes, it's fine. English allows for these things, as I am sure the OP knows.

Answer (score 1):

**the urban-rural gap** is not a phrase I've heard used by US news outlets but would assume it refers to a *disparity* of some kind, probably in income, between urban populations on average and rural populations.

P.S. The pattern `the adjective-adjective noun` is well-established. The pattern often presents an *opposition*. Compare:

> the male-female divide
>
> the Catholic-Protestant schism
>
> the lunar-solar conflict
>
> the liberal-conservative split

You will sometimes see a slash:

> the federalist/anti-federalist debate

P.P.S. **gap** is somewhat different than **divide**  inasmuch as **gap** often implies a difference in *level*, that is, **gap** is used in quantitative rather than qualitative circumstances. Compare: *the male-female pay gap*. It isn't just that the two entities have different or competing *outlooks*; with **gap** one of them is used as the touchstone against which the other is measured.

Comment: Can you suggest why it is a natural grammatical form ('urban-rural' is noun attribute, but even moreso a noun-noun attribute)?

Comment: @Mitch: What do you mean by "*natural* grammatical form"?  Not ungrammatical? *urban* and *rural* are adjectives, BTW, but adjectives can be nominalized.  I don't see it in any way different from phrases like *the male-female divide*.

Comment: TRomano: oops, right, both adjectives. The OP is asking if 'urban-rural' is grammatical, and it is, even formally. But I don't have a copy of CGEL to check if has been recognized. I'm sure it's not a pattern taught in EFL classes.

Comment: @Mitch. Where exactly does OP ask that? In the title? "proper English"?

Comment: Yes, the title.

Comment: Edited to put that question in the body (because without it, the body really has no question at all).

Comment: @TRomano: Thanks. I appreciate your detailed answer but I was not confused about the urban-rural combination. It's just that "urban-rural gap" is not what I'd use to refer to disparities between urban and rural areas and it's an expression I've never seen before.

Comment: @DavidRoss So what is it exactly about the phrase that is bothersome, 'urban-rural', 'divide', the combo, something else? Have you seen something else instead of 'urban-rural gap'? What would you use instead? 'urban-rural divide'? 'urban-rural differences'? Something else entirely?

Comment: @DavidRoss: please see the P.P.S.